# data report replay attacks?

Tags: replay-detection

Does anyone have pointers to a certain type of replay attack that I would call "data report" replay attacks, or past data injection attacks?

In short, I am not talking about traditional network replay attacks where an attacker records traffic and repeats valid transmissions going through the network (e.g. for identity theft), I am referring to attacks where an attacker compromises a node of a sensor network and replays data reports that the node sent the previous week let's say, to influence the base station into making bad decisions.

For instance, we could imagine someone tempering with his/her smart meter to send out data reports from when there were no appliances plugged in, or an attacker that compromises a power sensor of a smart grid to mess up with the state estimator, or again an attacker that emits ADS-B data s/he got from the internet next to an airport to fake the presence of aircraft (or AIS data and ships, same stuff).

I guess we can say that this is a subcategory of false data injection attacks, where the type of injected data is actually genuine past data.

I am looking for detection approaches (monitoring, report analysis) published in scientific papers but not necessarily, it can be approaches openly discussed in a blog post for instance.

I am also interested to know if anyone has come up with some sort of taxonomy for this type of replay attack (generic of domain-related), i.e. a formalization of all the attack variants.

Comment: Here's an article https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7370787. You should try Googling "Protect against False data injection attacks".

Comment: Hi Raimonds, thank you for the link. I have been studying FDIAs for some time now, and what I want to know is more specific. I am wondering if there are people working on replay attacks that can be compared to recording CCTV footage and play it back at a later time, thus hiding what is actually going on in front of the camera (like in the movies).